# Reading configuration file same directory as class returns null

Tags: java

I am not sure why I cannot read my configuration file which is in the same level as my class.  I have tried both code below but both inputstreams are null.

```
public MyClass
    public void getConfigurations()
    {
        String fileName = "myFile.conf";

        InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        InputStream inNew = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        System.out.println(in);
        System.out.println(inNew);
    }
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.getConfigurations();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
null
null
```

Here is my directory

```
MyProject
    -src
        -com
            -test
                -MyClass.java
                -myFile.conf
    -lib
```

I am going to package this class into an executable jar file so I would like it to work in both windows and linux.
When I package the jar file, I want the configuration file to be on the same level as my class.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Ho do you execute your code? Your conf file is in the same directory as the _java_ file. But is it copied along to the compiled _class_ files as well?

Comment: I think while searching for resources such as config files you should put your conf file into resources folder. I cannot really determine where it should be in your case, but in "classic" structure it should look like this: src/main/java for the java class and src/main/resources for the config file.

Comment: I am not using any resources folder...I just wanted to read it from my class. I am checking if I can open an inputstream into my config file from my class

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use absolute path (path beginning with `/`), in this situation you cannot get your file location.

Because you execute `.class` file, not the `.java` file. If you build your class in another folder, with relative path, your path is based on where the `.class` file is.

Try to put class file in the same dir as java files. I guess now you put them in `build` folder.

Or, try to get them like `/src/com/test`. This is absolute path.